# how to apply Django crispy_forms to create an attractive layout?

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

i tried the following code to create a form using Django crispy_forms but when it rendered gives simple html for layout

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Submit



class SimpleForm(forms.Form):

    username = forms.CharField(label="Username", required="True")
    password = forms.CharField(label="Password", required="True", widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    remember = forms.BooleanField(label="Remember Me !")

    helper = FormHelper()
    helper.form_method = 'POST'
    helper.add_input(Submit('login', 'login', css_class='btn-primary'))
```

**index.html**

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/home/vish/demo/new_form/form_demo/templates/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>

    <body>
          <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
         {% crispy form %}
        </div>
          </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

what's I'm doing wrong ? Please suggest the necessary improvements.

Comment: Do you know about bootstrap? you should use!

Comment: I have already added it in index .html but its not working

Comment: `href="/home/vish/demo/ne...` <- there's your problem, check your console, i bet you're getting a 404 on bootstrap's css

Answer (score 1):

You can define the layout, for example:

```
self.helper.layout = layout.Layout(
    Div(
        Div(
            Fieldset('',
                Div(
                    Div(
                        'first_name',
                        css_class="col-sm-6",
                    ),
                    Div(
                        'last_name',
                         css_class="col-sm-6",
                    ),
                    css_class="row",
                ),
            ),
            css_class='row'
         ), 
    )
```

Obs: I used bootstrap classes in this example, that what you should do!